# synchronizing on enum monitor

Tags: java, monitor, synchronized

I read that from 1.5 we can use enum for singleton

```
public enum Singleton {

  INSTANCE;

  //Singleton method
  public void someMethod( ) {...}
}

Singleton.INSTANCE.someMethod( );
```

Does this mean every entry in an enum type is a instance by itself?
If I define a enum type with a class,can I use block synchronization on every entry in teh enum type?

```
class smokers extends Thread{

    public enum restype{
        TOBACCO,MATCH,PAPER 
    }

    public void run(){
        if(xxxx){

        synchronized(restype.PAPER){
                    ....
            }
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(restype.MATCH){
                    ....
            }

        }
    }
```

Is this valid code?

Answer (score 1):

`TOBACCO,MATCH,PAPER` each is instance of type `restype`.

You can't modify enum constants, so don't need to synchronize.

If you want to use them as object locks, yes it is valid.

NOTE: Java naming convention suggests that use first letter as Capital letter for class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about `Enums` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
Since its a constant and has only one instance you don't need synchronization.

But if you are changing values of members using setters then you will need to add synchronization.

```
public enum Restype {
    TOBACCO(1), MATCH(2), PAPER(3);

    private int value = 0;//I have purposefully not declare it as final

    private Restype(int value) {
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {// now I can change value in multiple
                                        // threads.
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now I will have various ways to achieve synchronization for `setValue` and `getValue` easiest will be to declare them `synchronized`.

**But clearly above is Misuse of Enums.**

In java you can have syncrhonized block on any object so you can have synchronized block on enum instances also.

```
synchronized (Restype.TOBACCO) {
        // Allowed not recommenced 
        //every class should define its own mutex
    }
```

Comment: Even it enum is a singleton, if it's used on this `Smokers` class, synchronization is still needed, as there might be more than one Instance of `Smokers` running concurrently

Comment: @Chirlo I have added code snippets to elaborate more. I hope it clears doubts. If enum members are not declared as `final` then it is needed

Answer (score 0):

The code looks valid, but if you need to do that, put the logic in the enum

```
public enum RestType{
    PAPER{
        public synchronized void foo(){ return true };
    },
    MATCH{
        public void foo(){ return false };
    };

    public abstract boolean foo(); //I've never see an abstract method define a 
                                   //synchronized method... so I have not 
                                   //idea if it's valid
}
```

Comment: he should then stil synchronize the metho, for example: `PAPER{
        public synchronized void foo(){ return true };
    }'